# Convention for pointer *

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Out of curiosity; why is convention for pointers in C languages like this:

`NSString *str = ...`

Wouldn't be more appropriate to write:

`NSString* str = ...`

because we are defining pointer to NSString? (in Objective-C methods we do have (NSString*)parameter1 convention)

Again - I'm asking out of curiosity and to be able to better understand logic behind this... I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel or start flame war.

Comment: in the bible (k&r) they stick to star-to-the-right convention, even though pointer type it's a type.

Comment: This question has got to be a dup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you declare multiple pointer variables in a single declaration, you must write

```
char *a, *b;
```

since the declaration

```
char* a, b;
```

would declare `a` as a char pointer, but `b` as a plain char. IOW, this spacing shows that the asterisk really binds to the name only where it appears.