# Cleaner regular expression code in C?

Tags: c, regex, glib, software-design

I've got a C program that processes output from some shell commands. For 'ps', I'm interested in the following five fields. I specify the fields that I want by name, build the pattern for the glib regex engine, and then parse and process the results.

Is there a good way to organize fields, patterns, and formats/types that yields readable and maintainable code? What I have so far works, but doesn't look so good. I'm developing on OS X, but will want to port to other platforms later.

Also is there a way to get behavior like C#'s @ string operator to eliminate half my back slashes in the patterns?

Thanks.

```
const char field_pid[] = "pid";
const char field_lstart[] = "lstart";
const char field_ruser[] = "ruser";
const char field_cputime[] = "cputime";
const char field_command[] = "command";

char pattern[] = "\\s*(?<pid>\\d+)\\s+(?<lstart>\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d+\\s+[\\d:]+\\s+\\d+)\\s+(?<ruser>\\w+)\\s+(?<cputime>[\\d:\\.]+)\\s+(?<command>.+)";

// Do the regex match.
...

// Extract the matching strings.
gchar *pid = g_match_info_fetch_named(match_info, field_pid);
gchar *lstart = g_match_info_fetch_named(match_info, field_lstart);
gchar *ruser = g_match_info_fetch_named(match_info, field_ruser);
gchar *cputime = g_match_info_fetch_named(match_info, field_cputime);
gchar *command = g_match_info_fetch_named(match_info, field_command);

// Parse and process the strings.
...
```

Comment: I edited your code to put the pointer operator next to the variable it is being operated on, as the space before and after it makes it look like multiplication.  More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339763/convention-for-pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several improvement options:

- use the `G_REGEX_EXTENDED` option to compile the pattern. This will make whitespace in the pattern ignored, and `#` can be used to introduce comments until end of line.
- split the regex into several lines.
- read the regex from an external file instead of picking it up from the C source. (You can write a utility function for this, or use glib's configuration reading mechanisms.) This is the only way to cure the backslashitis.

Barring the last suggestion, the resulting regex might look like this:

```
const char *pattern = "\
\\s*                                  \
(?<pid> \\d+ ) \\s+                   \
(?<lstart> \\w+ \\s+ \\w+ \\s+ \\d+ \\s+ [\\d:]+ \\s+ \\d+) \\s+    \
(?<ruser> \\w+) \\s+                  \
(?<cputime> [\\d:\\.]+) \\s+          \
(?<command> .+)                       \
"
```

Still far from perfect, but much more readable than what you started with.

Comment: you could also build it up from #defines which would remove the continuation line \s and would allow you to give descriptive names for each part.